# Slather Gem installation giving error

Tags: ruby, macos, macos-high-sierra, slather

Slather installation is giving error in Mac.

ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError) You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory.

Answer (score 0):

For zsh, ensure that your ~/.zshrc has this:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Then restart shell. You should be able to run rbenv commands.

Answer (score 0):

Slather README:

> Setup for Xcode 5 and 6

Do you really want to use a gem that old?

```
Slather installation is giving error in Mac.

    You don't have write permissions for 
    the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory.
```

Good thing.  You don't want to mess with your system's ruby or else you might render your computer inoperable.  Instead, install [rvm](https://rvm.io) or [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) and use it to install your own ruby in your user directory (/Users/You)--where you have write permissions.  Then you can do whatever you want to your own ruby.